# How to determine root of network unreachable error thrown by Docker

Tags: linux, networking, docker, netplan

I'm trying to configure docker to run on an old SuperServer of mine, and can't get the networking bits setup correctly. Network config and Docker errors are below, ideas and suggestions are welcome.

The command which triggered the error was:

```
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer --restart unless-stopped
```

**Network Config**

```
network:
bonds:
    bond0:
        addresses: [10.0.0.57/24]
        #dhcp4: yes
        interfaces:
        - enp5s0
        - enp6s0
        parameters:
            lacp-rate: fast
            mode: 802.3ad
            transmit-hash-policy: layer2
ethernets:
    enp5s0: {}
    enp6s0: {}
version: 2
```

**Docker Status Output**

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-07-23 12:48:07 UTC; 2min 55s ago
Docs: https://docs.docker.com
Main PID: 3967 (dockerd)
Tasks: 9
CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
       └─3967 /usr/bin/dockerd -g /media/egg/docker -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Jul 23 12:48:06 aragog dockerd[3967]: time="2019-07-23T12:48:06.296307788Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Jul 23 12:48:06 aragog dockerd[3967]: time="2019-07-23T12:48:06.668399643Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip
Jul 23 12:48:06 aragog dockerd[3967]: time="2019-07-23T12:48:06.885466182Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Jul 23 12:48:07 aragog dockerd[3967]: time="2019-07-23T12:48:07.137260239Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=aeac949 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=19.03.0
Jul 23 12:48:07 aragog dockerd[3967]: time="2019-07-23T12:48:07.137992573Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Jul 23 12:48:07 aragog dockerd[3967]: time="2019-07-23T12:48:07.277043882Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Jul 23 12:48:07 aragog systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Jul 23 12:49:26 aragog dockerd[3967]: time="2019-07-23T12:49:26.970022388Z" level=warning msg="Error getting v2 registry: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp 34.199.40.84:
Jul 23 12:49:26 aragog dockerd[3967]: time="2019-07-23T12:49:26.970220199Z" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial
Jul 23 12:49:26 aragog dockerd[3967]: time="2019-07-23T12:49:26.970403292Z" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.40/images/create returned error: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2
```

~

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Can you connect to the network with something like curl? `curl -vL https://registry-1.docker.io/`

Comment: I'm not behind a proxy, but here's the output from that command: 
    Trying 34.233.151.211...
    * TCP_NODELAY set
    * Immediate connect fail for 34.233.151.211: Network is unreachable

Comment: Seems that curl and docker agree, your host cannot reach the external network. This does not appear to be a docker issue.

Comment: Thats odd, because apt has no issue reaching out. Also, `curl -vL https://www.google.com` works just fine

Comment: Do you reside in an embargoed country or have other firewalls that would prevent external access?

Comment: No sir, I'm around Atlanta Ga